# Android Studio: There are unrecoverable which must be corrected first

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, import

I can't import an eclipse project to android studio.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGpeL.png)

Hope someone can help me with this issue. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You should tell us what those errors are.

Comment: Error message: 'There are unrecoverable which must be corrected first'. I cant import 'GCMPushNotificationExample' in Android-Studio.

Comment: Yeah I saw this. What's the real error message? It's not fully visible in your screenshot.

Comment: I am sorry. here:http://pastebin.com/vA3B2Pj3

Comment: `Library reference ...google-play-services_lib could not be found` - guess you should remove that and add the gradle deps as mentioned in the *GCM* docs.

Comment: Try to post the build.gradle file